# How do I replicate the MongoDB API paradigm?

Tags: php, oop, mongodb

[MongoDB's excellent PHP driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) allows me to write to write PHP code that looks like this:

```
$mongo = new mongo("mongodb://path.to.my.server.com:27017");
$cnt = $mongo->db_name->table->count();
```

What's more, I can also write similar code on nonexistent tables:

```
$mongo->new_db_name->table->save(array('name' => 'Jimmy'));
echo $mongo->new_db_name->table->count();
```

The `Mongo` class is the parent object created by the `Mongo()` constructor, and it seems to create child `MongoCollection` variables (`db_name` and `new_db_name`, respectively) on the fly, as needed. How does the Mongo driver do this? How does it know to create an object of type `MongoCollection` if a public variable isn't found? The driver is a PECL C extension; is that necessary to replicate this behavior, or can someone do something like that in PHP?

Comment: It uses a variety of the following: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Nice link, I didn't know about many of those. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class like this to achieve the same:

```
class mongolike {
  protected $dbs;
  function __get($name) {
    if (empty($this->dbs[$name])) {
      $this->dbs[$name] = new db($name);
    }
    return $this->dbs[$name]
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I didn't know about many of those magic functions, always something new to learn.